# Python Array problem

Tags: python, arrays

I have an array that I have to add a new value to array value.  I am new to arrays.
how do I loop thru the array and add to the value in the existing array.

Comment: Confused, what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: Spell this question backwards and you'll hear "I sing because I live with Satan" !

Comment: It's probably best if you provide an example input and output.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> print [x+2 for x in [1,2,3]]
[3, 4, 5]
>>>
```

*Learn about Python lists and [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)*

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [2, 3, 4]
for i in range(0, len(a)):
  a[i] += 3
print a #prints [5, 6, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with arrays and need to do some math I would definitely recommend you **numpy**. Numpy was made for this purpose. Another hint (to all what I know): try to avoid loops where you can.

Reason: The code reads more clearly and is very likely to be faster.
Here an example what numpy can do:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: x = np.array([4,5,6,7,8])

In [3]: x+3
Out[3]: array([ 7,  8,  9, 10, 11])

In [4]: x**2
Out[4]: array([16, 25, 36, 49, 64])

In [5]: x>=6
Out[5]: array([False, False,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

For further reading I recommend the [numpy tutorial](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/quickstart.html#head-b43db272311d8133ab8ba29b6e8ff921da5e792d).